# Create an empty list from a list of string python

Tags: python

I am struggling to find a way to initialise a list of string to become empty lists with the strings as the names.
So essentially take

```
l = ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

and then make it so I can call y (not 'y') and get it to return an empty string [] that I can work with. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Does a dictionary work for you?

```
l = ['x', 'y', 'z']
empties = {i: [] for i in l}
```

And `empties['y']`, for example, will return `[]`.

Comment: Yea I have been thinking about using dictionaries, it would be easier, but would have to do a fair bit of re-writing to accommodate it. Also just kind of curious now as to if it is even possible.

Comment: there's a question called "how can I dynamically create variables in Python with a while loop" (don't know how to link to it on mobile). the most voted answer suggests a dictionary, but there's another one involving globals that might suit your needs. (buyers beware: many people downvoted that answer for, well, messing with globals)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question and to not tell you want to - or not to do:

[`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) will return a dictionary of the local variables in the current scope. You can add items to it:

```
>>> for i in l:
...     locals()[ i ] = []
...
>>> x
[]
>>> y
[]
>>> z
[]
```

Comment: This is unfortunately kind of brittle. When `locals()` doesn't return the `globals()` dictionary, changes to the return value won't propagate by default. There's some kind of trick to force an update, but I forget what it is.